# Angularjs compile a directive inside ng-repeat with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive in the form of a dropdown, pretty simple. The user can click a button to add as many as they need to in a `ul`, make their selections, and save it off. This is all inside of several `ng-repeat`s.

I'm having trouble mastering the scope. As I expected, this works:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups" question-group="group" class="question-group">
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="case in question.cases"></li>
      <li><new-case group='group'></new-case></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I say "works", I mean that `group` is properly scoped (the data of the entire `group` is necessary for the resulting input).

When I switch it to "click to add":

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups" question-group="group" class="question-group">
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="case in question.cases"></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="createNewCase($event)">add case</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

`group` is `undefined` in the scope. Here is my `createNewCase` function:

```
function createNewCase($event) {
  var thisLi = angular.element($event.target).closest('li');
  var listItem = $compile('<li><new-case group=\'group\'></new-case></li>');
  var html = listItem($scope);
  thisLi.before(html);
}
$scope.createNewCase = createNewCase;
```

And the `newCase` directive:

```
angular.module('groups.directives.newCaseDirective', [])
    .directive('newCase', ['$window', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'EA',
          scope: { group: '=' },
          templateUrl: 'groups/views/newcase.tpl.html'
        };
      }]);
```

I've been reading for days and I've tried a few other derivatives but I'm ultimately just not getting it. Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `group` is created by `ng-repeat` and is only available in child scopes of `ng-repeat`.

Each repeated element is in it's own child scope. So your directive version works but your other one doesn't because the controller doesn't see those child scopes.

You would have to pass `group` as argument of the function if you want to access it in controller

```
<a href="#" ng-click="createNewCase($event, group)">
```

Comment: Okay, so in the `createNewCase` function (in my original post) how would I compile the HTML with the newly added `group` argument?

Comment: curious why you don't stick with the directive that was working. Normally controllers aren't used for dom manipulation

Comment: Also....all you would need to do in controller is push a new object to the groups array....you don't need to add those elements yourself. Let angular manage the dom for you

Comment: A bit tough to explain...so is an admin interface for some questions and which ask follow up questions based on answer criteria (`case`). In "read" mode, the `case`s are simply `<li>{{case.expression}}, {{case.result}}</li>`. I want to, through the page, add items to that list. Because `expressions` and `reuslts` are fixed (from another part of the interface), I wanted a dropdown for each. So `createNewCase` appends two `select` inputs and a save button. Maybe my design is fundamentally flawed?

Comment: Doesn't sound flawed , I'm just not quite sure what your process flow is. Adding a new item to any ng-repeat however is just a matter of pushing object to array. Angular will detect the change to that array and redraw the dom

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps I could turn my `<li>{{case.expression}}, {{case.result}}</li>` into a directive which has a 'read' and 'write' version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101537/discussion-between-honus-wagner-and-charlietfl).